# Navigate to next view controller after delay ios

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uiviewcontroller, selector

I want to navigate to next view controller after a delay of 3 seconds. It happens, but it happens twice!. This is my code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let authToken =  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"token") as? String ?? ""


    if (authToken.characters.count == 0) {
        self.perform(#selector(ClassName.navigateToMobileScreen), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
    }
}
```

I placed this in both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear in different scenarios. What can be the problem with this?

Comment: You should put the codes of viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear. Because I think the problem might be in that scenario definition only.

Comment: Check your logic in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear...and make sure it is working as expected.

Comment: also add the code of viewDidLoad

Comment: earlier i added the same code in viewDidLoad, now there's nothing inside viewDidLoad

Comment: so then it might be pushing only once right? the only thing remaining is the delaying the push?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to load next view controller, and call this `loadNextVC` method from wherever you want(`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or any other method)

```
func loadNextVC() {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
    // Code to push/present new view controller
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that too, still the same result.
but when i just place the code without timers, it works

Comment: I think you are making some mistake.. otherwise above code is working perfectly fine.. i have used in my many projects.. and works perfectly fine

Comment: If you can share you whole file.. then possibly i can help you out/ point out the mistake that you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean to make sure your code to push the next ViewController will pushed only once.

```
var isNextVcPushed = false
func pushNextVc() {
    let authToken =  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"token") as? String ?? ""
    if (authToken.characters.count == 0) {
        if !isNextVcPushed {
            isNextVcPushed = true
            self.perform(#selector(ClassName.navigateToMobileScreen), with: nil, afterDelay: 3)
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method in every situation you need it. It will only push once.